# Thresholds in Static discipline

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, digital-logic

The Voltage thresholds \$V_{OH},\ V_{OL},\ V_{IH},\ V_{IL}\$ as far as I understood, they represent,

\$ V_{OH}\$ ~ The sender must produce a voltage above \$ V_{OH}\$ for sending a \$1\$
\$ V_{OL}\$ ~ The sender must produce a voltage below \$ V_{OL}\$ for sending a \$0\$
\$ V_{IH}\$ ~ The receiver must treat all voltages above \$ V_{IH}\$ as \$1\$
\$ V_{IL}\$ ~ The receiver must treat all voltages above \$ V_{IL}\$ as \$0\$

Questions:

1. (Notations) Shouldn't the subscripts be the other way? (i.e) \$V_{OH}\$ must be \$V_{IH}\$, since \$V_{OutputHigh}\$ is associated with sender, it must be  input high, not output high, similarly for all the others.
2. In [this lecture (48:00)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6vqWasIHaw) (MIT OCW Anant Agarwal), he checks the standards for a NOT gate that he constructed using a MOSFET as a switch. I don't understand how he checks the standards. Which one is the sender, which one is the receiver? He compares the \$ V_{OH}\$ & \$ V_{OL}\$ with \$V_{out}\$ curve and \$ V_{IH}\$ \$ V_{IL}\$ with \$V_{in}\$ curve, which again takes me to the first question. Don't the thresholds apply only to the interval in which the signal pass from one input element to other, so how does he check the standards with the curve (v_out) that is obtained after processing the signal given by an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Shouldn't the subscripts be the other way?*

No it should not. The parameters are described from the viewpoint of **this** circuit, not the circuit(s) connected to it. We do not know anything about the circuit that will produce the input signals or how the output signals will be used. My \$ V_{OH}\$ will simply describe what my circuit delivers, it says nothing about the circuit which will be using that signal so there is no point specifying limits for the input (\$ V_{IH}\$) of the next circuit.

In the video the lecturer simply draws the Input-Ouput curve of the NMOS + drain resistor circuit. He takes some shortcuts as he treats the NMOS as an ideal switch which is open when Vgs < Vt and closed when Vgs > Vt, where Vt = 1 V.

Then he looks at the output voltages. He just defines a 0.5 V margin so \$V_{OH}\$ becomes 4.5 V (5 V - 0.5 V) and \$V_{OL}\$ becomes 0.5 V.

To make the output high the input needs to be low (this is an inverter!) again he chooses a margin, in this case 0.1 V. Theoretically \$V_{IL}\$ < 1 V but at 1 V that would be on the edge. With a 0.1 V margin \$V_{IL}\$ then becomes 0.9 V.

Also, theoretically \$V_{IH}\$ > 1 V as the NMOS will switch on when Vgs > 1 V. Again the lecturer **sucks a margin out of his thumb** and makes \$V_{IH}\$ = 4 V that's a large margin!

All in all, I do not think you should be paying too much attention to this as what he's doing is more practical than scientific. For example: the 0.1 V margin of \$V_{IL}\$, where does that come from? Is 0.1 V enough? Maybe it would need to be 0.2 V to counter for fabrication variations in the NMOS transistor.

I think you should only try to understand the general process that he's doing: determining input-output relations and determining the parameters from that.

Comment: I get that, can you please take a look at 48:00 of the lecture and take me through the process of checking the standards

Comment: I added some text related to that part of the video.

Comment: Please tell me one thing, these parameters are placed on what? On a device or on the signal that is taken from one device(sender signal) and given to another device (receiver) or something else

Comment: I understand this: whatever be the process happening in the middle, we just look at input and output signals and they must be disciplined, am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

\$ V_{OH} \$ is the minimum and \$ V_{OL} \$ is the maximum voltage of an output in the high and low states respectively when driving a specified load.

\$ V_{IH} \$ is the minimum input voltage that is guaranteed to be read as a '1' and \$ V_{IL} \$ is the maximum input voltage that is guaranteed to be read as a '0'.

Generally \$ V_{OH} > V_{IH} \$ and \$ V_{OL} < V_{IL} \$ for any given logic family to ensure reliable operation allowing for some voltage drop along the connections between devices.

Comment: I get that, can you please take a look at 48:00 of the lecture and take me through the process of checking the standards